# Cannot call chrome.tabs.executeScript() into preloaded tab. Is this a bug in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

**All I want to know is if what I've described is the intended behavior or a bug in Chrome.**

When you enter a URL into the omnibar, chrome preloads an invisible tab in the background, and swaps it in when the user hits Enter.

Content scripts are also inserted into preloaded tabs. I have a content script that contains one line:

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ msg: 'init' });
```

The background page waits for this message and dynamically loads a script into the tab that sent the message.

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function(request, sender) {
    console.log('Loading script.js into frameId: ' + sender.frameId + ', tabId: ' + sender.tab.id);
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(sender.tab.id, {
      file: 'script.js',
      frameId: sender.frameId,
      runAt: 'document_start',
      matchAboutBlank: true
    });
  }
)
```

The background page also listens for tab replacement events.

```
chrome.tabs.onReplaced.addListener(
  function (addedTabId, removedTabId){
    console.log('Tab id changed from ' + removedTabId + ' to ' + addedTabId);
  }
);
```

script.js is dynamically loaded into most tabs without a problem. However, preloaded tabs are a problem because the value sender.tab.id is apparently invalid

The following image shows the background page's console.

[background page console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5EwhZ.png)

Each line corresponds to the following actions:

1. Open a new tab (which has tabId 2812)
2. Start typing in URL bar (preload happens behind the scenes in tabId 2814)
3. Background page attempts to call chrome.tabs.execute script into tabId 2814 but fails
4. 3 seconds later, hit enter to load URL. Finally, the onReplaced event fires indicating a tabId changed from 2812 to 2814.

This all seems backwards to me. Does that mean it's impossible dynamically execute a script into a preloaded tab?

[My extension showcasing this behavior](https://github.com/lusakasa/saka-key)

Comment: Yes, such tab becomes real only if the user confirms navigation in which case it's reported in onReplaced event and becomes visible for chrome.tabs API. I guess the reason is that until that moment it doesn't have what it takes to be a tab internally. BTW the id of such tabs is always `-1` until the swap.

Comment: Is there any way to identify whether a MessageSender belongs to a preloaded tab?

Comment: When I read sender.tab.id in the onMessage callback, I always get the id the tab will assume if it turns into an actual tab. However sender.tab.index is -1.

Comment: Ah, yes, that's it! That's the `-1` I remembered.

Comment: Thanks. This seems like a dirty hack... but whatever works.

Comment: `index` being -1 means the tab doesn't yet have a place in the tab strip so checking it seems proper. Too bad this is not documented.